# Returning custom error in spring security filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am working on a Spring Boot & Spring Security application that makes use of JSON Web Tokens.

I have a spring security filter that checks for the presence of an existing JWT and if so, injects a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken:

```
public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Value("${api.token.header}")
    String tokenHeader;

    @Autowired
    TokenUtility tokenUtility;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        String incomingToken = httpRequest.getHeader(tokenHeader);

        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null && incomingToken != null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = null;

            try {

                userDetails = tokenUtility.validateToken(incomingToken);

            } catch (TokenExpiredException e) {

                throw new ServletException("Token has expired", e);
            }

            if (userDetails != null) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

This filter is injected as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {

        authenticationManagerBuilder
                            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {

        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter() throws Exception {

        AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new AuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());

        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // filter injected here
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

If a user passes in a token that has expired, they receive the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp":1496424964894,
    "status":500,
    "error":"Internal Server Error",
    "exception":"com.app.exceptions.TokenExpiredException",
    "message":"javax.servlet.ServletException: Token has expired",
    "path":"/orders"
}
```

I know that spring security intercepts the requests before they make it to the controller layer, so I can't use my existing @ControllerAdvice to handle these exceptions.

My question is, how do I customise the error message/object that gets returned here? Elsewhere I use a JSON-serialized POJO to return error messages and I want to be consistent. I also don't want the user to see `javax.servlet.ServletException`

Answer (score 3):

First, modify JWTTokenProvider Class to add a custom header to Http Servlet Request using setAttribute() method.

```
   public boolean validateToken(String token,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
    try {
        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token);
        return true;
    }catch (SignatureException ex){
        System.out.println("Invalid JWT Signature");
    }catch (MalformedJwtException ex){
        System.out.println("Invalid JWT token");
    }catch (ExpiredJwtException ex){
        System.out.println("Expired JWT token");
        httpServletRequest.setAttribute("expired",ex.getMessage());
    }catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex){
        System.out.println("Unsupported JWT exception");
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
        System.out.println("Jwt claims string is empty");
    }
    return false;
```

}

Then modify commence method in JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint class to check expired header in http servlet request header that we added above.

```
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                     HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                     AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

    final String expired = (String) httpServletRequest.getAttribute("expired");
    System.out.println(expired);
    if (expired!=null){
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,expired);
    }else{
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Invalid Login details");
    }
```

}

For more details see this [Post](https://medium.com/fullstackblog/spring-security-jwt-token-expired-custom-response-b85437914b81?source=friends_link&sk=87cd3ef90dfe5066e996f6da222563b7). A nice simple solution.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: just added the solutions

Answer (score 1):

As you are using .exceptionHandling() I believe you can configure a new ExceptionHandler;

Another way would be to override the messages you want to be different, like this [post](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/display-custom-error-message-in-spring-security/)